# Convert number format in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, formatting, etl

Need some help please ..
I have excel data that is formatted. Example 33.257615111 shows as 33.258 (thirty three million two hundred and fifty eight thousand)

I am trying to import data file into SQL using SSIS ETL. Is there a way I can convert this during ETL process as a number with 2 decimal places? i.e. 33257615.11

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done.  Use a Derived Column and the `ROUND()` expression.

Inside your Dataflow, between the Excel File Source component and the OLE DB Destination component, add a Derived Column component.  Inside that Derived Column component create a new column that rounds the value.

`(DT_NUMERIC,25,2)ROUND(MyColumnName, 2)`

Map this new Derived Column above to your SQL destination and we are all set.

But! **Are you SURE you want to store rounded numbers in your database?**

Will you ever need to sum this column?  If so, the rounded values are going to yield a very different total than the non-rounded values.  Maybe, don't do this rounding in SSIS and instead store the full numbers.  Let applications reading this data do the formatting.  It's just as easy.

```
SELECT ROUND(MyColumnName,2) AS MyColumnName
FROM MyTable
```

In [multitier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Other_considerations), the formatting of numbers should be left up to the display layer, not the data layer.  This is exactly what Excel is doing.  It's *showing* you a rounded number, but behind the scenes is the full value.  Don't drop precision for the sake of formatting.